# Dynamic font size is not working?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I want to give dynamic font size the the label & text view in the app.For that i have made some custom classes for that.

**For label**

```
#import "CustomLabel.h"

@implementation CustomLabel


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:self.font.fontName size:((self.frame.size.height / self.numberOfLines) - 4)];
}


@end
```

I have added this class for the label but when i run the app then it does not show any label.Please tell where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call UILabel's `drawRect` from yours.

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
    self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:self.font.fontName size:((self.frame.size.height / self.numberOfLines) - 4)];

    [super drawRect: rect];
}
```

Comment: you don't call drawRect: of the superclass so UILabel doesn't get a chance to draw itself. Add `[super drawRect: rect];` as I suggested in my answer and see if it helps.